# PHP Function to Restore JSON File from String?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a PHP script that pulls data from another program; that program outputs its data as a single JSON file.  But for reasons I'll never understand, the author of the other program decided to remove all newlines and white spaces from the JSON file and submit the whole output as one enormous string:

```
{"John":{"status":"Wait"},"Jennifer":{"status":"Active"},"James":{"status":"Active","age":56}}
```

This is practically useless.  I need my PHP script to take the above and reconstruct the original file into a human-readable format:

```
{
    "John": {
        "status":"Wait"
    },
    "Jennifer": {
        "status":"Active"
    },
    "James": {
        "status":"Active",
        "age":56
    }
}
```

I could develop such a method from scratch, but that would be a pain.  I've been reading up on `json_decode()`, which I believe could help me parse the original string, but not really reconstruct the original file.  Does anyone know of a library or something that might help?  Thanks

Comment: JSON is a data serialization format, and human-readability is not a priority. Nor is whitespace significant or required. That said, see the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option [in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode).

Comment: _"But for reasons I'll never understand"_ Those reasons are, "because JSON isn't _supposed_ to be human-readable, that's the whole point" and, "being in a nice machine-readable format like JSON means you can easily put it into whatever human-readable format you like."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. decode JSON string into PHP  array
2. encode again using option JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

```php
echo json_encode(json_decode($json_text, true), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[Test json_encode and json_decode](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/be0b615c78919feb3209a264d61f1fc1/php/php8/af6abaf015a98cf3d55ad61fa2848bd0/)

Comment: Yesssssssssssss!  AMAZing!!!  This worked perfectly, thank you!